# How to get arguments by hooking classes

Tags: ios, arguments, jailbreak, syslog, theos

Is it possible to write code that enable outputting "C" message to /var/log/syslog?

```
%hook classA
- (id)MethodB:(int)C
{
   //something
   return %orig;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do :

```
%hook classA
- (id)MethodB:(int)C
{
    NSLog(@"C value : %d", C);
    return %orig;
}
%end
```

or :

```
%hook classA
- (id)MethodB:(int)C
{
    %log;
    return %orig;
}
%end
```